# Can a braided stream create thick relatively continuous siltstone beds?

Tags: geology, sedimentology

I am attempting to interpret an outcrop I went to. I suggested it was created by a braided stream. The one thing I cannot explain are prominent alternating siltstone and sandstone beds.  There are smaller lenses of silstone that I suggest are abandoned channel fills, but I have other siltstone beds about 0.2 - 0.5 m thick that seem pretty continuous (laterally continuous up to ~ 10-15 m as far as I can see).
[image: outcrop]

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a picture to help us get a good insight

Comment: without images this description is pretty merger and makes helping you difficult. A picture is worth a thousand words and you don't have many words ot begin with.

Comment: @EtienneGodin  Here is a photo!

Comment: Any more hints, where is it, and when is it ?

Answer (score -1):

Braided channels are usually found in estuaries. Estuaries are usually on the coast. That being the case, it seems possible that now and again a high tide brought in some sand which covered the silt-filled channels, which then brought more silt, thus creating the layered structure you describe. If the site is now a long way from the coast, it doesn't follow that it always was.

Comment: Braided channels are not restricted to coastal environments. They are also common in mountain/glacial settings, although in those cases you should find coarse grains, i.e. gravels, not only silt/sand.

Comment: Not a specialist, but i was under the impression that they are usually indicative of the proximal reaches, where sediment load and slope are high. But i may be wrong and can't contribute more without guessing ...

Comment: The channels of many North American Prairie rivers (e.g. the Platte) were naturally braided until engineers got to them.